# QT C++ communication to Arduino Leonardo

Tags: c++, arduino, qt-creator

So basically I've been struggling with the issue that I can send a message to the leonardo with qt c++ however when I try to send another message it just doesn't arrives for some reason, while it worked with autoit (so I'm 100% confident that the code I used on the leonardo works flawless, and I'm still a big noob at c++)

```
void _sendcomm(QByteArray _send2comm) {
if (serial.isOpen() && serial.isWritable())
{
        serial.write(_send2comm);
        serial.flush();
}
else {
    qDebug() << "fail ;/"; //however even when calling this the second time this doesn't set off...
     }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    _start();
    foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
            //qDebug() << "Name        : " << info.portName();
            //qDebug() << "Description : " << info.description();
            //qDebug() << "Manufacturer: " << info.manufacturer();
            if(info.description() == "Arduino Leonardo") {
                _aport = info.portName();
            }
            serial.setPort(info);
        }
    if(_aport.isEmpty()) {
        qDebug() << "none found";
    }
    else {
        serial.setPortName(_aport);
        serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
        serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
        serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
        serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
        serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::TwoStop);
        serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
                _sendcomm("light;1\r\n"); // this one arrived on the arduino
                Sleep(1500);
                _sendcomm("light;120\r\n"); // this one never arrives, I created the input on the leonardo so when it receives light;num it set's the brightness of the lcd keypadshield.

                serial.close();
    }
    w->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Is there anyone who can point me out where I'd made the mistake and/or how to solve this?

Comment: added serial.waitforbyteswritten(500) which doesn't error out either so idk what is going wrong

Comment: Well, I've been coding 35 years and I'm never 100% confident that any code "works flawless". How is the Arduino attached to whatever your qt c++ program is running on? Can you post the Arduino code? Or if not, do you have any way to trace the serial traffic? I don't know exactly what sendcomm does, but my money would be on the arduino side right now. What is "autoit"?

Comment: @Greycon, I got it working mate, don't know yet how to turn this post to solved when I fixed it.... basically i shouldn't have send \n with it... that fixed it. btw if you don't know what autoit is.. it's an scripting language basically like autohotkey, see autoitscript.com for it